# mido on Python 3.5.1: No module named 'mido'

Tags: python, midi, python-3.5

I'm trying to use `mido` with Python 3.5.1. I have successfully installed it (it says "successfully installed mido-1.1.14" in command prompt) but when I tried to import it in python, it gives me the message

> ImportError: No module named 'mido'

I understand that `mido` targets Python 2.7 and 3.2, but does it really not work with 3.5 at all? Or am I missing something here?

I'm using Windows 8.1, 64-bit; but my Python 3.5 is 32-bit version. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: 8 questions and no up votes! You posted a high-quality post as a new user, so have an upvote!

Answer (score 1):

Installing a module for one python version does not install it for the others.

If you're using pip, run something like `pip3 install mido`.  `pip` defaults to installing for Python 2, so you'll need to explicitly call `pip3`.

Comment: I tried doing that and I get this message: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): mido in (path). What does this mean?

Comment: @FeliciaAgatha It means it's already installed. Can you try installing using `pip3.5` instead? And try importing using `python3.5`

Comment: Installing using `pip3.5` is giving me the same message. I'm not too sue what you meant by importing using `python3.5` though. I tested the it using Python 3.5 shell

Comment: @FeliciaAgatha I mean on the terminal try `python3.5` then type `import mido` when the `>>>` prompt appears

Comment: In the Command Prompt, try running `> pip3.5 install mido`. Try reloading (restarting) your interpreter if that doesn't work